# Quick charge negotiation device

Tags: usb, charging

I'd like some advice on how I can negotiate a Qualcomm Quick Charger up to a certain voltage. I have a "dumb" appliance which usually uses its own transformer/"wall wart" at 12V 1A. I also have a USB Quick Charge adapter which can supply 12V 2A, so in theory I can create a cable to adapt that USB charger and replace the wall wart. However, the charger won't output 12V unless a charge controller tells it that the device can use the extra voltage. This negotiation is usually performed by a charge controller on a smart phone.

Is there a simple device on the market that can do this? Alternatively, is there a circuit I can put together to accomplish this? Here is a diagram which illustrates the idea. Basically I need to output 12V to a "dumb" device, so an independent charge controller is needed.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As found in the duplicate answer, the device I was looking for does exist, and can be found under the name "quick charge trigger board".

Please note, however, that if the power bank or USB adapter that you're trying to trigger quick charge from doesn't license and implement Qualcomm QC2.0 or QC3.0, the trigger board may not work for you. For example, the board worked for me on my Motorola "turbo charger" which implements QC2.0, but it would not trigger Quick Charge on a Lenovo quick charger. Further research showed that Lenovo has sort of made up their own charging protocol, so trigger boards using the Qualcomm QC standards will not be able to communicate with these.